# What is the Correct Method of Paging Resources using REST

Tags: json, rest, http, http-headers, restful-architecture

I have two examples below showing two competing implementations for paging using REST. Which is more 'correct'?

In both cases below I am using the standard [Link](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) HTTP header to add URL's to next, previous, first and last pages.

### Describe Pages in Response Body

```
GET /foo?page=1&count=3

Content-Type: application/json
Link: </foo?Page=2&Count=3>; rel="next", </foo?Page=1&Count=3>; rel="first", </foo?Page=2&Count=3>; rel="last" 
{
  "page": 1,
  "count": 3,
  "totalCount": 9,
  "totalPages": 2,
  "items": [
    { "item": 1 },
    { "item": 2 },
    { "item": 3 }
  ]
}
```

I have heard that this is not REST'ful because it changes the resources response body. However, what if you changed the URL to be `/foo/pages?page=1&count=3`, now you are describing a `page` resource and not a `foo` resource.

### Link & X-Pagination HTTP Header

```
GET /foo?page=1&count=3

Content-Type: application/json
Link: </foo?Page=2&Count=3>; rel="next", </foo?Page=1&Count=3>; rel="first", </foo?Page=2&Count=3>; rel="last" 
X-Pagination: { "page": 1, "count": 3, "totalCount": 9, "totalPages": 3 }
[
  { "item": 1 },
  { "item": 2 },
  { "item": 3 }
]
```

Using this method means that the response body has not changed but I am using a non-standard HTTP header to describe the total number of items and total page count.

Comment: I really wonder why you need to solve this via REST. Pagination should be manages client side. I recommend to build your REST-GET in a way that you can submit "start" und "limit" paramenter, it doesnt need to know anything about pages.

Comment: I’d definitely pick the first option and always have an `"items"` key.

Comment: @Ryan Care to elaborate as to why?

Answer (score 1):

I guess they are both okay. It depends on how you define the accessed resource.

- If you define to access a **page resource**, your first example would
  be correct. (Assuming that defining no page properties would lead to a default page)
- If you define to access your **resource with a
  paged representation**, your second example would be correct. This would go to the direction of content negotiation.

I suggest you simply go with what suite you best. Personally I would tend to example one, as it's easier to use and just more intuitive

REST is only an architecture. It can be implemented in many ways, depending on definitions. There is not one correct solution.

> I have heard that this is not RESTfull because it changes the
>   resources response body.

Well content negotiation is a valid way to change the representation of the resource. (Which alters the response object but not the resources itself)

Answer (score 1):

> However, what if you changed the URL to be /foo/pages?page=1&count=3, now you are describing a page resource and not a foo resource.

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your identifiers.

It does, however, map different identifiers to different resources.  Which is to say

```
/foo
/foo?page=1&count=3
```

These two identifiers point to *different* resources; there's no particular reason that the response body (ie, the representations), of these resources needs to be the same.

In addition to [RFC 5005](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005) (which defines the link relations that you are using), you may also want to look into how the [Twitter timeline API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines) is designed.